# Как в ContextMenuStrip ComboBox_Enter загрузить данные из столбца таблицы SQL?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как в ContextMenuStrip ComboBox_Enter загрузить данные из столбца таблицы SQL? Или там не Enter должен использоваться, а что-то другое?

[image: в этой форме]

код:

```
public void toolStripComboBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string conStr = @"Data Source=ZUBA\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=diplom; Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
    con.Open();

    SqliteCommand select_protocols = new SqliteCommand("SELECT Название FROM proekti ORDER BY Название", con);
    using (SqliteDataReader select_protocols_read = select_protocols.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (select_protocols_read.Read())
        {
            if (!contextMenuStrip1.Items.Contains(select_protocols_read.GetString(0)))
            {
                comboBox.Items.Add(select_protocols_read.GetString(0));
            }
        }
    }

    //string lala = "SELECT*From proekti where Название";
    //SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(lala, con);
    ////SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select*from proekti where Название='", con);
    //Proekto();  
}
```

Comment: Зачем вам в меню комбобокс? Вы же просто можете наделать меню айтемов в подменю и выбрать одно из них?

Comment: aepot, мне надо чтобы при нажатии на назначить на проект, подгружался столбец таблицы sql, там же всегда может быть по разному , то 2 проекта, то 0 проектов